# fabric.js : How to make an image in the shape of a circle with white borders

Tags: image, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to create some animations on HTML canvas. I need to make this :

[image]

If I use image element I cannot make it circular and not put white border.
If I use circle object I cannot put an image in it.

Any ideas will be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try someting like this with `clipTo` function:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURL, function(oImg) {
    oImg.scale(1.0).set({
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        stroke : 'white',
        strokeWidth : 100,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
          }
    });
    canvas.add(oImg).setActiveObject(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6Y6k/8/

Comment: How to add a white border to it?

Comment: `stroke : 'white'` and `strokeWidth : 100`. Official documentation: [stroke](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#stroke) and [strokeWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#strokeWidth). Please consider to vote for the response.

Comment: clipTo has been replaced by clipPath in 2.4.0, see http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part1